# Equivalent definitions of homotopy

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $H$ be a continous map $I\times X\longrightarrow Y$. Then why is the functin $I\longrightarrow C(X,Y)$, $t\longmapsto h_t$, where $h_t(x)=H(t,x)$ continous? Conversely, if $h\colon I\longrightarrow C(X,Y)$ is continous, why is $H\colon I\times X\longrightarrow Y$, $(t,x)\longmapsto h_t(x)$ continous? Here, $I$ denotes the real unit interval. I am wondering, because I have read, that in general, there is no bijection $\hom(W\times X,Y)\cong\hom(W,C(X,Y))$ for topological spaces. Can someone tell me, where the properties of $I$ play a role?

Comment: I don't think this is true.  You typically need conditions on $X$, not on $I$, for this to be true.

Comment: @EricWofsey I found the claim here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Homotopy.html And also https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy here I interpreted the definition for enriched categories this way. If the claim is not correct, then which one is the right definition for a homotopy to use?

Comment: It might help to know that when we say that $h_t:X \rightarrow Y, x \mapsto h_t(x)$ is a continuous map, we mean that the associated map $H: I \times X \rightarrow Y, H(t,x) = h_t(x)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned at [Top](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Top), one sometimes (and often without comment) takes **Top** *not* to mean the category of all (point-set) topological spaces, but instead some other [convenient category of spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convenient+category+of+topological+spaces). I generally assume any page on nLab that talks about **Top** means to do such a thing.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, which definition is to be prefered  for general point set topological spaces?

Comment: @user114885: **CGHaus**, the category of [compactly generated Hausdorff spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactly+generated+topological+space) is popular.